# How to remove an account from Serverfault but leave other stackexchange sites intact

Tags: support, account

I am fine to leave my questions and answers, but I don't want my name associated with them or anything else on this site. Please answer my question about removing my name/account from this site.

Comment: `the sysadmin subreddits` - yow. /r/sysadmin is full of pretty terrible advice on a regular basis. Proceed with caution. Also, I edited out your story, as it's not relevant to the question and will likely draw downvotes. There are plenty of other meta questions about the attitude/direction of the site in general, you can add it there if you'd prefer.

Comment: The fact that 90 percent of the information I had in my post had been modded out when I provided disclaimers about them being my personal opinion and took efforts to not be inflammatory is symptomatic of the problem here.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal Meta.SF is not for venting regardless of intention. it's for asking about site problems or policies.

Comment: You're free to roll back the edit if you disagree. I was doing it so that your question didn't get downvoted off of the front page (-7 does that).

Comment: I must have misinterpreted the discussion tag, I am getting good answers here so my diatribe was unnecessary.  I thought it might have been useful to explain why I am leaving, but I am going to go ahead and guess most people leave here for the same reason, and it isn't a secret.

Comment: What discussion tag? Your question is tagged [support] and [user-accounts]

Comment: It was a suggested tag when I was tagging the post that I created here.

Comment: I'm not following your logic there. If you want to have a discussion about the site, post in one of the dozen questions that are already open about the site's direction. If you want to ask for support on how to delete your account, ask for support on how to delete your account. Don't try and do these two *different* things in the same question.

Comment: I know, I chose not to choose the tag because I didn't want to give the impression that I was looking to be convinced not to leave or anything to that effect, but the description of the tag made me think that this forum was appropriate for an opinionated post.  Regardless, it really doesn't matter at this point.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why everyone thinks Mods can't delete users, but we most certainly can.

Comment: I feel a great disturbance in the force...

Answer (score 5):

Simply fill in the form at https://serverfault.com/contact and select the "I need to delete my user profile" option. It will automatically populate the form with your profile URL

Answer (score 3):

The [Contact Us](https://meta.serverfault.com/contact) link at the bottom of each page takes you to a form. One of the options on the 'What can we help you with' drop down is what you want.

Good luck.